# require()  fails even though file_exists() claims file is there

Tags: php, include

Here is my code:

```
if (file_exists('config.php')) {
    require('config.php'); // This is line 38
}
```

Which somehow produces the error:

> Warning: require(config.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/name/file.php on line 38

How on earth is this possible?

Update: The following **does** work:

```
if (file_exists(getcwd(). '/config.php')) {
     require(getcwd(). '/config.php');
}
```

Comment: Weird. Can you try a `clearstatcache()` prior to these lines?

Comment: Doesn't seem to affect anything. See my updated question.

Comment: how about `is_readable()` instead? file_exists isn't particularly useful in this case, as you need the file to actually be readable by your script. think of it as the difference between "is there money in the bank vault?" and "can I take some of the money in the vault?"

Comment: you are missing the current directory in the include path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to ignore the include path:

```
if (file_exists('config.php')) {
    require('./config.php'); // This is line 38
}
```

if it works you are missing . directory  into the include path and you have to choose to include it or using relative path file names

You can change your include_path with a php configuration directive (if you can change the php config file) or resort to **get_include_path()** and **set_include_path()** on a per file/project base

ex: `set_include_path('.'. PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());` in your first line of php (or in a common configuration file);

Sources:

- [include php manual](http://www.php.net/include)
- [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)
- [set_include_path](http://www.php.net/set_include_path)
- [get_include_path](http://www.php.net/get_include_path)

Comment: Thank you to you and Ed Heal for the explanations. This is what was happening.

Answer (score 7):

Try absolute path. Using `dirname(__FILE__)`.

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php');
```

Comment: or just ```require( __DIR__ . '/config.php' );```

Comment: @Igor `__DIR__` was not very  available in 2012

Comment: Yeah, I just added it since the answer was still useful for me today.

Answer (score 5):

The PHP `include` and `require` operate in the same way and use an include path ([include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)). Therefore will use this path to find the file and if you have not set it correctly it will not look in the current directory.

Use [get include path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php) to find out the value for this.