# imagejpeg() unable to open for writing - sometimes it works, sometimes not

Tags: php

I try to save an image resource to an image by the following code:

```
imagejpeg ($destination_res, $destination, 100);
```

The script also contains a file-upload which does work (the files always exist in the destination folder) - after this file upload I want to use this file for `imagejpeg()`. The problem is that sometimes my code does work, sometimes not. In case of not working I get the following error by PHP:

```
Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open [path] for writing: Invalid argument in script on line xy
```

I guess that there is a problem with the copying process - maybe the copying process after the file upload is not completely finished and therefore it is not writeable.

But I also tried to check if `file_exists($destination)` and if file `is_writable($destination)` before the `imagejpeg()` command. Both checks return `TRUE` even in case of the warning error.

If I put a `sleep(2)` between file upload and `imagejpeg()` fewer errors happen. The longer the sleep lasts, the fewer errors occur.

Can anyone help me?

I'm working on my PC with OS `Windows 8` - I use `IIS 8` and `PHP 5.3.3`.

Comment: can you post your code also not just one line?

Comment: This might help you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448584/require-fails-even-though-file-exists-claims-file-is-there

Comment: you can directly use imagejpeg ($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] , $destination, 100);

Comment: "The longer the sleep lasts, the fewer errors occur."  
Based off of this statement, it sounds like your bug lives somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Maybe a racing condition between several PHP processes writing to the same temporary image file?

Answer (score 2):

PHP has an internal cache for used path, when you create files, it could be that the cache gets outdated and PHP throws error, even if files are there (some miliseconds later)...

To avoid problems with created files which can not be found in realtime use [**`clearstatcache()`**](http://php.net/manual/function.clearstatcache.php). It resets the internal PHP cache for paths.

Call `clearstatcache()` after you create files, and before you access created files.

```
clearstatcache();
imagejpeg ($destination_res, $destination, 100);
```